# Talend Installtion on Ubuntu

Tags: talend

I would like to install Talend Open Studio on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but the Talend website shows only download options for Windows and Mac only. Where do I find the Linux version?

Comment: You need juste to lunch the binary after extraction of the files. No install needed.

Comment: @abdoulsn the binary is not lunchable on Linux

Comment: Of course! you're stuck??

Answer (score 3):

If you download the Windows version, you should receive a zip file. The zip file should contain binaries for both Windows and Linux. To start the Studio on Linux, just run the bash script contained within.

I'm not sure why they don't label the download as Windows and Linux, hopefully they fix that at some point to make it a little clearer.

Comment: when i download it saved as 7.2 exe file and getting error while click on the same.please let me know how to get zip file

Comment: @Muniaraj Thangavelu What link are you using? You should be getting a zip file. Try one of the links [here](https://community.talend.com/t5/What-s-new-and-announcements/Talend-Open-Studio-v-7-2-1-is-now-available-for-download/td-p/165312). I just tried this myself - it's a bit confusing as there's no explicit option for Linux, but clicking on "Windows Download" will get you the zip. There's a bash script in there for running the binary.

Comment: @aseriesofdarkcaves as for now, Windows version gives you an exe file, not zip.

Comment: @jutky What link are you using? Downloading any of the Windows variants from https://www.talend.com/products/talend-open-studio/#t3 gives me a zip.

Comment: @aseriesofdarkcaves I use Windows download button for "Open Studio for Data Integration" and it gives me this file: TOS_DI-20200219_1130-V7.3.1-windows-installer.exe

Comment: @jutky I see what you mean - "Open Studio for Data Integration" seems to be the only one that results in an exe. I tried every other download except that one... I'll post in the forums to let them know - hopefully it will be fixed. I see you got a zip from Sourceforge - ideally they should allow the download from their website...

Comment: Here's the forum post https://community.talend.com/s/question/0D53p00008NeCcuCAF/download-page-only-offers-an-exe-download-for-open-studio-for-data-integration - hopefully they fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to download zip file here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/talend-studio/files/latest/download